# C++ Stack around the variable '' was corrupted. (D3D9)

Tags: c++, directx

I know there are many similar questions, but I can't see any with this specific issue. The code runs fine in Release mode, but gives me "Stack around the variable 'indices' was corrupted." when I compile in Debug mode. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

This is the code with the issue:

```
// Create Saturn rings
// create the vertices using the CUSTOMVERTEX struct
#define num_vertices 1000
CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[num_vertices];

nSections = 150;
float outerRadius = (80000000 + escalaa[6]) / escalaa[6];
float innerRadius = (7000000 + escalaa[6]) / escalaa[6];
float endAngle = ToRadians(360);
float beginAngle = ToRadians(0);

float angle = endAngle - beginAngle;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= nSections; i+=2)
{
    float t = (float)i / (float)nSections;
    float theta = beginAngle + t * angle;
    float s = (float)sin(theta);
    float c = (float)cos(theta);

    vertices[i] = { c * innerRadius, 0, -1 * (s * innerRadius), { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f }, 4, 2 };
    vertices[i + 1] = { c * outerRadius, 0, -1 * (s * outerRadius), { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f }, 2, 4 };
}



// create a vertex buffer interface called v_buffer
d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(num_vertices* sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
    0,
    CUSTOMFVF,
    D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
    &v_buffer,
    NULL);

VOID* pVoid;    // a void pointer

// lock v_buffer and load the vertices into it
v_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
v_buffer->Unlock();

// create the indices using an int array
short indices[num_vertices];

int aa=0;
for (int n = 0; n < num_vertices; n += 6)
{
    indices[n] = aa;
    indices[n + 1] = aa + 1;
    indices[n + 2] = aa + 2;

    indices[n + 3] = aa + 2;
    indices[n + 4] = aa + 1;
    indices[n + 5] = aa + 3;
    aa += 2;
}

// create an index buffer interface called i_buffer
d3ddev->CreateIndexBuffer(3 * num_vertices* sizeof(short),
    0,
    D3DFMT_INDEX16,
    D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
    &i_buffer,
    NULL);

// lock i_buffer and load the indices into it
i_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
memcpy(pVoid, indices, sizeof(indices));
i_buffer->Unlock();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This loop is broken:

```
for (int n = 0; n < num_vertices; n += 6)
{
    indices[n] = aa;
    indices[n + 1] = aa + 1;
    indices[n + 2] = aa + 2;

    indices[n + 3] = aa + 2;
    indices[n + 4] = aa + 1;
    indices[n + 5] = aa + 3;
    aa += 2;
}
```

You need to be testing for `(n + 5) < num_vertices` instead.  Eventually `n` will be 996, which is less than `num_vertices` (1000) and so the loop will continue to run, but 996 + 4 is 1000, which is out of the array bounds.  Reading from or writing to `indices[n + 4]` (and beyond) when `n` reaches 996 is therefore undefined behavior and writing to it appears to be corrupting the stack.

Beware that changing the loop condition this way will cause `indices[996]` through `indices[999]` to be uninitialized!  This means that your call to `d3ddev->CreateIndexBuffer()` will likely be triggering a read of an uninitialized object, *which is also undefined behavior.*  You might consider redefining `num_vertices` to be a multiple of 6 to avoid this problem.

Note that undefined behavior can result in any behavior, *including* the program "running fine" or at least appearing to do so.